# How to update UITableViewCell constraint's constant and update cell's height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uiimageview, autolayout

I've got a problem with self sizing cells under iOS8 and autolayout (pure autolayout, no `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`).

I've got two `UITableView` subclasses. Both contains some kind of header (static height), footer (also static height) and "content" with dynamic height. Dynamic content in first one is `UILabel` with line number set to 0 and it works like a charm, it's set synchronously in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (it's important!). `NSString` is set to `UILablel.text`'s and voila.

Second type is `UIImageView`. The image is downloaded asynchronously, with `AFNetworking`'s `UIImage` category. In the completion block I'm setting `UIImageView`'s `UIImage` and updating calculated constraint's constant:

- It's a height constraint,
- it's as an outlet,
- `UIImageView`'s width is fixed, height is calculated
- height depends on image's size

Now, what I've tried:

- calling `layoutIfNeeded` in `UITableViewCell`'s subclass - doesn't work at all
- setting up a delegete, and calling `-cellNeedsUpdate:(UITableViewCell *)cell` and with this method:

  - reloading row at cell's indexpath - it causes strange scrolling behavior
  - calling `layoutIfNeeded` and begin/endUpdates on `UITableView` - this one was very starnge, random rows appears, cell's background color changes
- varoius combination of above - results odd behavior or doens't work at all

Is there any way to set it properly  without scrolling issues?

Answer (score 0):

On the main thread, call:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

This will force the tableview to recalculate the height for all visible cells.

Comment: As I wrote before - it causes odd scrolling issues

Comment: Don't call `layoutIfNeeded`. If this doesn't work, there's likely something wrong with your implementation. Can you upload a basic sample project that reproduces this behavior?